# C: Input text during runtime without setting a fixed array size before

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, runtime, c-strings

I am relatively new to C programming and I have therefore some problems.

My problem is that I couldn't figure out how to input a certain text and saving it into a char array, without a fixed size, during runtime.
Is it possible for the compiler to recognize the text size and then allocating the memory during runtime?

I've implemented a function for ROT 13 encryption and I want the user to insert a text.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: you can use Linked List for dynamically allocating memory

Comment: You can start with a small amount of memory obtained by `malloc`. Input char by char, and when the array is (almost) full (allow 1 for a string terminator), use `realloc` to increase the array length.

Comment: @Vishal How? You would have to allocate memory dynamically to have a linked list that tracks dynamically allocated memory. And how would you use that for strings? Character per node?

Comment: @WeatherVane So do I have to use a loop and the getchar() function to do this?

Comment: @MelvinTomKlimke please see my answer showing the technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to acquire memory as you need it by using `realloc`. I would use `CHUNKSIZE` more than `4` but I restricted it for easy testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNKSIZE   4

int main(void){
    char *text;
    int maxlen = CHUNKSIZE;
    int index = 0;
    int ch;

    text = malloc(CHUNKSIZE);
    if(text == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter your text:\n");

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        text[index++] = ch;
        if (index >= maxlen) {
            maxlen += CHUNKSIZE;
            text = realloc(text, maxlen);   
            if(text == NULL)
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    text[index] = 0;                // terminate

    printf("You entered: %s\n", text);
    free(text);    
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
Enter your text:
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
You entered: A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: @MelvinTomKlimke please "accept" if you think this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Run this program.It will help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
int n,i,*ptr,s=0;
char *pt;
if( argc == 2 ) {
    for(i=0;i<argv[1][i]!='\0';i++){
    s++;
}
printf(" %s\n", argv[1]);
printf("array size is= %d\n", s);
pt=(char*)malloc(s*sizeof(char));
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
pt[i]=argv[1][i];
for(i=0;i<pt[i]!='\0';i++)
printf("%c",pt[i]);
   }
   else if( argc > 2 ) {
      printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("One argument expected.\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: The code might address the problem of the OP, but I wonder whether it is helpful for them without any explanation. Could you therefore please add some explanation how to run your program and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

In **c**, if you want to allocate the memory dynamically you should use "new" operator.  for example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>                                                                                  
    #include <stdlib.h>                                                                                 
    #include <ctype.h>                                                                                  

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {                                                                  
    if (argc < 2) {                                                                                   
      printf("Usage: a.out num\n");                                                                   
      return 0;                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                 

    int size = atoi(argv[1]);                                                                         
    printf("the size is %d\n", size);                                                                 
    int *t = new int[size];                                                                           
    delete[] t;                                                                                       

    return 0;                                                                                         
  }
```

Comment: C does not have a "new operator"

Comment: Actually, in c++, the operator is "new"; in c, it is "malloc". generally, we use gnu compiler, so the difference between c and c++ is slight. Sorry for my mistake.